# Display list elements as if they were typed in

Tags: python, string, python-2.x

Here's the code:

```
test = ['26', 1, '050120', '084922', u'43034775', u'RRR', '', None]
print(', '.join(test))
```

It says:

> TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found

Is there a way to join without looking at element type?

```
', '.join(str(v) for v in test)
```

is not a good solution. It prints:

```
26, 1, 050120, 084900, 21747, 1200.0, X, X, 18034775, 5TDDK3DC4BS029227, , None
```

I want to leave element type as it is and print out as it is:

```
'26', 1, '050120', '084922', u'43034775', u'RRR', '', None
```

Comment: @ngShravil.py, I recreated the issue.

Comment: If you concat stuff you need them to be same type, so str

Comment: @hansolo, how? Could you please provide an example?

Comment: @timgeb, python 2

Comment: the result of `print("1")` is the same as `print(1)`.

Comment: Also quotes are not shown in simple printing, just when items are in list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) builtin.

```
print(', '.join(map(repr, test)))
```

This produces the desired output because

> For many types, this function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to eval()

Example:

```
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> str('1')
'1'
>>> repr(1)
'1'
>>> repr('1')
"'1'"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for printing purpose :

```
test = ['26', 1, '050120', '084922', u'43034775', u'RRR', '', None]

print(str(test)[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

To the your expected output `'26', 1, '050120', '084922', u'43034775', u'RRR', '', None`. Use the formatting of the list and remove the brackets

```
test = ['26', 1, '050120', '084922', u'43034775', u'RRR', '', None]
print(str(test).strip("[]")) # '26', 1, '050120', '084922', '43034775', 'RRR', '', None
```